# Jmeter linux shell cannot start server

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

**Situation:**

I have installed [Jasper Reports Library](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases) (V6.5.1) on my local Linux server which generates PDF reports (Data is dumped in a temp Oracle DB table for the reporting engine).

It then serves this PDF back to the website from which I kick off the process.

**Goal:**

Install Jmeter to analyse performance / possible bottlenecks of "Jasper Reports Library" (aka Report Generation) on my local linux server (I cannot access this server via GUI, only shell).

I understand I have to connect my local Windows 10 machine (running same Jmeter 4.0) with this local server. On the server I have to start Jmeter 4.0 Server (via jmeter-server command) however I get an error and am stuck (have not found anything online or even people with the same goal unfortunately...)

**Steps I have taken:**

- Download latest (4.0) bin from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- Extracted on local linux server in /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin
- Trying to start server with /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java jmeter-server (the default java version is 6 so through this I can run this app with java 8) - [Instructions found here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running)

-> Getting error: "Error: Could not find or load main class jmeter-server"
[image]

Any help regarding above or even any other tool you may use are appreciated (Maybe there is a preferable way to test performance for the above scenario)

Comment: what's the error when you call only `jmeter-server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 aspects related to your issue and screenshot:

**1)** Using java 8 instead of 6 - This can be done in several ways, depending on your needs and restrictions, such as the need to have Java 6 globally available for other applications and using 8 just to run JMeter, or just replacing 6 with 8 entirely. For the sake of brevity, I'll assume the first scenario, but there's documentation available for both and Dmitri T has partially explained it already.

Anyway, the same [JMeter doc link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) you used, describes (just scroll down a few times) how to create a `setenv.sh` script in the `bin` directory and configure `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` depending on your needs.

> To set those variables permanently, you can place them in a file called setenv.sh in the bin directory. This file will be sourced when running JMeter by calling the jmeter script.

You seem to be wanting a JDK, so create the script and add inside `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102`, save and exit.

**2)** Running JMeter - To clarify a minor confusion, `java MyCompiledClass` instructs java to [load and execute the "*program*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html#unix-2c) defined in `MyCompiledClass`, which is not what you want to do, because `jmeter-server` is a shell script. If you open it, you'll see that it calls the `jmeter` shell script which will do some configuration, end eventually call (in short) `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` with some arguments and options.

So, to run JMeter make sure your scripts are executable with `chmod`, and simply run from command line `./jmeter-server`. From the same link:

> Un*x script files; should work on most Linux/Unix systems:
>
> **jmeter** - run JMeter (in GUI mode by default). Defines some JVM settings which may not work for all JVMs.
>
> **jmeter-server** - start JMeter in server mode (calls jmeter script with appropriate parameters)
>
> **jmeter.sh** - very basic JMeter script (You may need to adapt JVM options like memory settings).
>
> **mirror-server.sh** - runs the JMeter Mirror Server in non-GUI mode
>
> **shutdown.sh** - Run the Shutdown client to stop a non-GUI instance gracefully
>
> **stoptest.sh** - Run the Shutdown client to stop a non-GUI instance abruptly

Comment: Thank you. Starting jmeter-server with JAVA_HOME config set to Java 8 did not throw the Class Error anymore.
To battle following errors I added following entries in the jmeter-server file

"RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.10.132" 

"SERVER_PORT=60000 jmeter-server"

-> Now when I start jmeter-server the server "freezes" (no feedback in the shell) and I have to physically restart the server

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you did, but configurations must be done to both machines for server-client distributed/remote testing. You can refer the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) for a step-by step config.

Comment: Well, I got jmeter-server to execute on Linux now, but "netstat -a | grep 1099" returns nothing... will open a new ticket because this seems like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Amend your [PATH environment variable](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) so Java 8 bin would be **before** Java 6 bin like:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin:$PATH && export PATH
   ```
2. Once done you should be able to just launch the `jmeter-server` script like

   ```
   pushd /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin && ./jmeter-server
   ```

More information:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Thanks. Now getting "/opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-4.0bin/bin /opt/dlins/apache-jmeter-2.6/bin Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
Could not create the Java virtual machine." will look into what that could mean...